# java.util.Scanner is not importing when using scanner

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  }
}
```

The import `java.util.Scanner` is not importing when I click `Alt+Enter` in `IntelliJ IDEA` and I need to write it myself. Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure you want to write an entire class rather than just figure out why it's not importing...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it is not excluded from import in *File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import*

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+O is a shortcut Optimize imports. simultaneously remove unused imports.
If its one or more import classes it will ask user to select