# Why should I import "java.util.*" in top of my code?

Tags: java.util.scanner

my question is that i want to use Scanner object or Arrays object for example for usage of Arrays.copyof, but before importing  java.util.* or  java.util.Scanner and  java.util.Arrays there is now object of them to use !
why this happens to me??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPhgm.png)

Comment: Perhaps because `Scanner` and `Arrays` part of java.util ??? I'd recommend to read about imports in Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Java import work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-does-java-import-work)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you want to achieve. Are you asking why you should do imports in Java?

`import` statements allow you to refer to classes which are declared in other packages without referring to their full package name. This is standard java practice. Inside your `main(String args[]` you can use `java.util.Scanner myobject = new ..` if you want, but that is too cumbersome and often you have multiple classes in a package that you want to use. So adding a simple `import java.util.*` is considered better.

Another tip is to use one among the large number of available IDEs (eclipse, sublime, IntelliJ) which will add the imports automatically for you.

Comment: actually my question is why the IntelliJ IDE doesn`t  import java.util.scanner automatically when i  use for example:" Scanner newscanner=new Scanner(system.in)

Comment: @MostafaKhoshbash Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261533/java-util-scanner-is-not-importing-when-using-scanner) question? or simply pressing Ctrl+Alt+O

Comment: it doesnt work u know without importing java.util.Scanner when i type Scanner it will be undefined and in red type and also there is no suggestion java.util to automatically imported!